# error when using ycsb tool for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, benchmarking, ycsb

i am trying to test mongodb using ycsb tool.i installed java and maven and i have downloaded ycsb-master from https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB  i run mvn clean package command so that mongodb binding is successful.To load the workload i executed the below command

> C:\YCSB-master\bin>c:\Python27\python.exe ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads\workloada -p recordcount=1000 -threads 6 -p mongodb.url="mongodb://localhost:27017" -p mongodb.database=test -p writeConcern=normal -p mongodb.auth="true"

but i am getting error like

```
[WARN]  Running against a source checkout. In order to get our runtime dependencies we'll have to invoke Maven. Depending on the state of your system, this may take ~30-45 seconds    
[DEBUG]  Running 'mvn -pl com.yahoo.ycsb:mongodb-binding -am package -DskipTests dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=compile -Dmdep.outputFilterFile=true'   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ycsb", line 259, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "ycsb", line 232, in main
    maven_says = get_classpath_from_maven(project)
  File "ycsb", line 178, in get_classpath_from_maven+ err.output)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

please help me